# If else doesn't work?

Tags: php, mysql, variables, if-statement, file-upload

I got an article edit function that automatically loads in the article details when selected. I am trying to see if a file was submitted or not during the edit (when resubmitted in edit mode). If the file is not submitted keep the image url in the database unchanged, else change the image url. Somehow the image url breaks when I do not submit a file during edit.

```
$article_id = $_POST['article-id'];
$article_title = $_POST['article-title'];
$article_description = $_POST['article-description'];
$article_image = $_POST['thumbnail'];
$article_content = $_POST['article-content'];

if(!isset($_FILES['article-thumbnail']) && 
   !$_FILES['article-thumbnail']['size'] > 0){
    $query = "UPDATE article
              SET article_title = '$article_title', 
              article_description = '$article_description', 
              article_content = '$article_content', published = 'NO'
              WHERE article_id = '$article_id'";

    if (!mysql_query($query)) {
        // Handle error here
        // e.g.
        echo "Oh no! The query failed! Error: ".mysql_error();
    }

    mysql_close();
} else {
    $valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "zip", "bmp");
    $max_file_size = 1024*100; 
    $path = "test/article_thumbnails/"; 
    $count = 0;

    $thumbnailPath = 'http://localhost:8888/test_cms/images/article-thumbnails/' . 
                      $_FILES["article-thumbnail"]["name"];

    // Loop $_FILES to exeicute all files
    foreach ($_FILES['article-thumbnail']['name'] as $f => $name) {     
        if ($_FILES['article-thumbnail']['error'][$f] == 4) {
            continue; // Skip file if any error found
        }        

        if ($_FILES['article-thumbnail']['error'][$f] == 0) {            
            if ($_FILES['article-thumbnail']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
                $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
                continue; // Skip large files
            } else if( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ) {
                $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
                continue; // Skip invalid file formats
            } else { // No error found! Move uploaded files 
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["article-thumbnail"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$name))
                    $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded file
            }
        }
    }

    $query = "UPDATE article
              SET article_title = '$article_title', 
              article_description = '$article_description', 
              article_image = '$thumbnailPath', 
              article_content = '$article_content', published = 'NO'
              WHERE article_id = '$article_id'";

    if (!mysql_query($query)) {
        // Handle error here
        // e.g.
        echo "Oh no! The query failed! Error: ".mysql_error();
    }

    mysql_close();
}
```

As you can see during the else statement the thumbnailPath is set to the url following the name of file:

```
$_FILES["article-thumbnail"]["name"];
```

What happens when I do not submit a file during the edit is it writes the url in the database without the file name. Even though it shouldn't get in the else clause?

Comment: remove the ! in both conditions

Comment: You need to read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) so you don’t create any more severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) like the one you have here. Remember, `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Comment: That doesn't work else it does not get in the else clause since the file is submitted then and running the query of not editing the url in the DB.

Comment: Yes thanks tadman, I am quite new to PHP and I am aware of the sql injection problem. I just wanted to finish the code first and review it later for those security changes.